# Declare Podspec with a dependency to an objc library

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am developing a Swift framework (MyFramework) that has a dependency to a third party static library written in Objc ([NewRelic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/installation/cocoapods-installation))

I am using CocoaPods 1.4.0 and I have declared my podspec like this:

```
...

s.source_files = 'MyFrame/Classes/**/*'

s.static_framework = true
s.dependency    'NewRelicAgent', '6.1.1'     # Obj-c

s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent.framework/Headers', 'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/MyFrameFramework' }
s.preserve_paths = 'MyFrameFramework/MyFrame.modulemap'
```

From what I read in different posts, what I think I am doing here is:

1. first declare a `static_framework` to be able to use a static library, NewRelic.
2. Set the NewRelic dependency.
3. Set the header paths to find the NewRelic headers and locate the modulemap as explained [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5271)

This is my `MyFrame.modulemap`:

```
framework module LGResources {
    umbrella header "MyFrameFramework.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

And this `MyFrameFramework.h`:

```
//! Project version number for LGResources.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for LGResources.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <Amplitude/PublicHeader.h>

#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h>
```

Inside my framework classes I am trying to use NewRelic but it does not work

[image]

I am starting to give up since I find confusing to have so many references in the [CocoaPod specs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#specification): `module_map`, `frameworks`, `vendored_frameworks`, `dependency`, `preserve_paths`, ...

Can someone please point me into the right direction? How can I declare a static dependency and use it inside my framework?

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I don't really know where should I put the `MyFrameFramework.h` file to be managed by CocoaPods, by I have tried different manual approaches with no luck.

Comment: hello, Could you find a solution for that?

Comment: Hey @Xavi I am facing same issue I have posted another question related to same on stackoverlow. Can you please tell me how do you resolve above issue. Can you specify you podspec here. Im integrating quantumgraph pod in my swift framework.

Answer (score 4):

There may be additional issues, but one problem is that NewRelicAgent.framework is missing a module map.

Static frameworks can have other static frameworks or static vendored_frameworks as dependencies. A static library is not sufficient. A module map bundled into a framework is necessary to tell the build system how to access its public methods from Swift or Objective C modules.

The [NewRelicAgent podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/1/a/2/NewRelicAgent/6.2.0/NewRelicAgent.podspec.json) is specifying a vendored_framework, but the [zip](https://download.newrelic.com/ios_agent/NewRelic_iOS_Agent_6.2.0.zip) is missing a module map.

It might be possible to come up with a workaround, but the best solution would be to convince the NewRelicAgent pod maintainers to update the pod.